# unblock public functions calls in Meteor.methods

Tags: meteor

This Meteor calls 2 public functions fun1 and fun2. Both are defined in Immediately-invoked function expressions.
How can I fire fun1 and right away also fire fun2 without having to wait for fun1 to finish? thx

```js
Meteor.methods({
  'runFunctions': function() {
    IIEF1.publicFun1();
    IIEF2.publicFun2();  
  }
})
```

Comment: publicFun2() WILL NOT wait for publicFun1()

Comment: It all depends on whether you have _asynchronous_ code within your IIFE's or not. If there is only synchronous code, there is no way to execute anything else before it completes. If they do have async code, then there is a high chance the 2nd one already starts before the 1st executes its callbacks.

Comment: If you really need multiple threads you might find https://www.npmjs.com/package/webworker-threads useful for creating threads server-side. On the client web-workers are also a possibility.